# Getting the next element in a list without using the index function in python

Tags: python, list

Suppose we have a list in python:

```
[102, -30, 112, -87, 113, -56]
```

How do you get the next element in the list given a certain element?
For example:

```
NextElementAfter(-87) => 113
```

Special Rules:

1. You can only use 1 list.
2. You can't use the index() function.

Comment: What have you tried so far? As this looks like a homework question, please read [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Comment: Looks just a homework. for list  if == return [+1]

Comment: `list(itertools.dropwhile(lambda v: v!=-87, [102, -30, 112, -87, 113, -56]))[1]`

Comment: Or (if your list is in `data`): `data[next(i for i,v in enumerate(data) if v==-87) + 1]`. So many different ways. @Coder48 What did you try?

Comment: @anurag I don't see how that answer is related to this quesion. Your link leads to an answer about converting a list of lists into a numpy array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mylist = [102, -30, 112, -87, 113, -56]

def NextElementAfter(ele):
    i = 0
    for char in mylist:
        if char == ele:
            break
        else:
            i += 1
    print(mylist[i+1])

myinp = int(input('Enter Number: '))
NextElementAfter(myinp)
```